# Can't org-clockin into the task in Org Agenda

Tags: emacs, org-mode, spacemacs

When I try `org-clockin` into the task from `Org Agenda`, I keep getting the following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Before first headline at position 80 in buffer *Org Agenda*")
  signal(error ("Before first headline at position 80 in buffer *Org Agenda*"))
  error("Before first headline at position %d in buffer %s" 80 #<buffer *Org Agenda*>)
  #[257 "\300\301`p#\207" [error "Before first headline at position %d in buffer %s"] 5 "\n\n(fn IGNORED)"]((error "before first heading"))
  funcall(#[257 "\300\301`p#\207" [error "Before first headline at position %d in buffer %s"] 5 "\n\n(fn IGNORED)"] (error "before first heading"))
  org-back-to-heading(t)
  #[0 "\n?\205\306 \307\211\211\310?\205\f@\2035\203#@\311=\2035A\2045\2045\307\311A\312 \210)\300\313\232\203E\311B\314\307C\"\210)\300\315\232\203`\316\317!\262\203\\\320!\262\202`\321\322!\210\300\323\232\203i\324 \210\203\307\212\204v\325\311!\210\326D!\203\204\326!\202\205p\232\205\243\327D!\203\227\327!\202\230`U\205\243E\330\331 8\232)\203\262\332\333F\"\210\334\335\307\"\210G\327H!\326H!\223\210\311A\336\307\311\"\210)m\203\326\337 \204\326\340\341!\202\327`\262\212\203\365\326!\203\365\342\326!!q\210\327!\262\307\211\223\210\212\214~\210b\210\325\311!\210\204\nG\307\211\223\210\343\344!\210\345 \210\330\331 8E\346I!\2039\307J\347K!\210)I\350\351!!\211\2035\352!\210\210\202OI\203O\347L\353I\354R!\204O\352I!\210M\203a\346M!\203aM \202s\330\331 8\203r\355\356\357\360\330!#\202s\361F\362N!\210N\203\267\347\363O\364\365R!\203\267\332\366\350\367!\"\210\370\350\367!\371Q\262\367\225b\210\372\373\374\350\367!!\"P\375`Q\"R\376\377 !S\202mN\201]=\203\331\332\201^!\210\201_ \210\201`\351!\210\334\335\307\"\210\202m\201a\201b!\210\201cu\210\201d \210\212\341\210\201e )\203\201f\367!\210\201g\201h \351Z!\210O\201i\261\210\375`Q\"R\376\377 !SB\203'C\206]\211\203R\201j\201k\201l\201m\201nT\311\"!\201m!Z\201o\245\"!\203R\211\206]\301\206]\201nT\311\"P\201pP\201q\201r#\262H`\201s \223\210D\212\325\311!\210`)\201s \223\210\311UV\201t=\204\232V\201u=\203\270W\204\244\201vW\201wW>\204\270\201xW\201y\"WV\201z=\204\312V\201u=\203\316XY\201{ \210Z\203\342\201|Z!\210\307ZV\203\363\201}[\211\201{#Z\\\203\201|\\!\210\307\\\201}\201o\211\201~#\\\332\201
#\210\343\201\200!,\207" [nil nil org-clock-resolving-clocks-due-to-idleness org-clock-resolving-clocks org-clock-leftover-time org--msg-extra org-clocking-p nil "" t org-resolve-clocks (64) org-clock-in (4) org-clock-select-task "Clock-in on task: " copy-marker error "Abort" (16) org-clock-mark-default-task org-back-to-heading marker-buffer marker-position 4 org-heading-components message "Clock continues in \"%s\"" throw abort org-clock-out org-at-heading-p point-at-bol 0 org-base-buffer run-hooks org-clock-in-prepare-hook org-clock-history-push functionp looking-at match-string 2 org-todo "[   ]*" "\\>" replace-regexp-in-string "\\[\\[.*?\\]\\[\\(.*?\\)\\]\\]" "\\1" match-string-no-properties "???" ...] 13 "\n\n(fn)"]()
  funcall(#[0 "\n?\205\306 \307\211\211\310?\205\f@\2035\203#@\311=\2035A\2045\2045\307\311A\312 \210)\300\313\232\203E\311B\314\307C\"\210)\300\315\232\203`\316\317!\262\203\\\320!\262\202`\321\322!\210\300\323\232\203i\324 \210\203\307\212\204v\325\311!\210\326D!\203\204\326!\202\205p\232\205\243\327D!\203\227\327!\202\230`U\205\243E\330\331 8\232)\203\262\332\333F\"\210\334\335\307\"\210G\327H!\326H!\223\210\311A\336\307\311\"\210)m\203\326\337 \204\326\340\341!\202\327`\262\212\203\365\326!\203\365\342\326!!q\210\327!\262\307\211\223\210\212\214~\210b\210\325\311!\210\204\nG\307\211\223\210\343\344!\210\345 \210\330\331 8E\346I!\2039\307J\347K!\210)I\350\351!!\211\2035\352!\210\210\202OI\203O\347L\353I\354R!\204O\352I!\210M\203a\346M!\203aM \202s\330\331 8\203r\355\356\357\360\330!#\202s\361F\362N!\210N\203\267\347\363O\364\365R!\203\267\332\366\350\367!\"\210\370\350\367!\371Q\262\367\225b\210\372\373\374\350\367!!\"P\375`Q\"R\376\377 !S\202mN\201]=\203\331\332\201^!\210\201_ \210\201`\351!\210\334\335\307\"\210\202m\201a\201b!\210\201cu\210\201d \210\212\341\210\201e )\203\201f\367!\210\201g\201h \351Z!\210O\201i\261\210\375`Q\"R\376\377 !SB\203'C\206]\211\203R\201j\201k\201l\201m\201nT\311\"!\201m!Z\201o\245\"!\203R\211\206]\301\206]\201nT\311\"P\201pP\201q\201r#\262H`\201s \223\210D\212\325\311!\210`)\201s \223\210\311UV\201t=\204\232V\201u=\203\270W\204\244\201vW\201wW>\204\270\201xW\201y\"WV\201z=\204\312V\201u=\203\316XY\201{ \210Z\203\342\201|Z!\210\307ZV\203\363\201}[\211\201{#Z\\\203\201|\\!\210\307\\\201}\201o\211\201~#\\\332\201
#\210\343\201\200!,\207" [nil nil org-clock-resolving-clocks-due-to-idleness org-clock-resolving-clocks org-clock-leftover-time org--msg-extra org-clocking-p nil "" t org-resolve-clocks (64) org-clock-in (4) org-clock-select-task "Clock-in on task: " copy-marker error "Abort" (16) org-clock-mark-default-task org-back-to-heading marker-buffer marker-position 4 org-heading-components message "Clock continues in \"%s\"" throw abort org-clock-out org-at-heading-p point-at-bol 0 org-base-buffer run-hooks org-clock-in-prepare-hook org-clock-history-push functionp looking-at match-string 2 org-todo "[   ]*" "\\>" replace-regexp-in-string "\\[\\[.*?\\]\\[\\(.*?\\)\\]\\]" "\\1" match-string-no-properties "???" ...] 13 "\n\n(fn)"])
  org-clock-in(nil)
  call-interactively(org-clock-in nil nil)
  command-execute(org-clock-in)
```

I tried updating org package, removing all my org-agenda files in case there is some problem with files, but nothing seems to work.
I am using latest version of spacemacs. Most of my org config come from this articles - http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html

This question was asked on emacs.stackexchange (I also gave bountry there) - https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24058/error-when-trying-to-clock-in-agenda-buffer

Comment: If you remove spacemacs from the equation, does the error still occur?  If spacemacs has no bearing on this question, then please consider removing the spacemacs tag from this question as well as any references to that library.  [Otherwise, people with some `org-mode` familiarity will skip over this question if they are not familiar with spacemacs.]  Also, please post a link to the duplicate question over at emacs.stackexchange.com (which you placed a bounty on).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I added the link to question on emacs.stackexchange. As for removing spacemacs, I will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `org-agenda-clock-in` instead of `org-clock-in`.

See:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-commands.html